# SharedPreferences not working as expected in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a help activity in my app and I want it to only launch in first run.

I have tried this:

In on create of Help Activity:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("firstRun", true);
editor.commit();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In onResume of Help Activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
if (!firstRun) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    Log.d("TAG1", "firstRun(false): " + Boolean.valueOf(firstRun).toString());
} else {
    Log.d("TAG1", "firstRun(true): " + Boolean.valueOf(firstRun).toString());
}
}
```

In onCreate of MainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
editor.commit();

boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
Log.d("TAG1", "firstRun: " + Boolean.valueOf(firstRun).toString());
```

But it doesn't shows help activity, and when it runs the app it just jumps into `MainActivity`!!

And I have an exit button in my app and when I want to exit the app with that button it just shows again `MainActivity` and didn't exit the app.

Comment: where have you specified to jump to the helpActivity?

Comment: First tip:  The code in `onCreate()` of HelpActivity is not needed.  Since you specify true as the default, you don't need to set it to true before `onResume()`, since it will default to true if there is no value present.  As for the exit button issue, please add your on click code for that button.  Also, please add your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @DanielNugent thank you for answer but I'm basic in android programming can you help me with codes? for example edit my wrong code to correct one and I'll accept your answer ;-)

Comment: Which activity is defined as the main/launcher activity?

Comment: In onCrate of Help Activity you are always starting a net MainActivity activity without checking firstRun.

Comment: @M4rtini Help Activity is the main. if you know answer please please help with codes I'll accept your answer

Comment: I would have set the `MainActivity`as the launcher activity. And then launch the HelperActicity from MainActivity that one time it is needed. If not you would be creating two activities on every app launch, which would slow down the startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this in onCreate of `MainActivity`. That is all you should need if you set `MainActivity` as the launcher activity. Which is what i would recommend.

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
if (firstRun) {
    settings.edit().putBoolean("firstRun", false).apply();
    //start help activity
}
```

With `MainActivity` as the launcher activity you should get faster launches, as you don't create two activities every time. And you avoid having two activities in the back stack.

ps: Google does not recommend the usage of an "exit" button. Rather you should rely on the back\home button to close the app and let the OS decide when the app is destroyed.
[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238)

Comment: so if i set MainActivity as luncher activity then I can't open help activity as a first run activity :/

Comment: The code above will launch the helpActivity on the first launch. Did that not work?

Comment: Can you describe what happens?

Comment: Try to uninstall and install the app again. The value of "firstRun" might be sticking around from before. If that don't help, then please add an edit to the question of how your code now looks.